# How to store a complex object in an Entity in EJB3?

Tags: jakarta-ee, properties, entity, ejb-3.0

I am working on a project of DVD shop, based on EJB3.

Through this project, the client can choose DVD and put the DVD in a shopping cart, and then the shopping cart will create a reservation record.

My problem is that I want the reservation to be an Entity (a table in database), but it has a property ShoppingCart which is a complex object; the Entity doesn’t support storage of complex object, I don’t know how to deal with this problem?

Can anyone give me any suggestion or better solution?

Here is the class:

```
    public class ShoppingCartItem {
      private DVD item;
      private int quantity;
    …
    }

    public class ShoppingCart {
      private HashMap<String, ShoppingCartItem> items;
      private int numberOfItems;
      …
    }

    @Entity
    public class DVD implements Serializable { 
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
      private Long id;
      private String title; 
      …
    }


    @Entity
    public class Reservation implements Serializable {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
      private Long id;
      //the problem is here
      private ShoppingCart cart;
      …
    }
```

Comment: It is true that I didn't know how to accept a good answer, but now I know.Thank you for reminding me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define what information about the `ShoppingCart` you are interested in persisting.

In the JPA Entity (which is what you refer to as "Entity in EJB 3") you can store:

- simple fields (Strings, integers, etc.),
- embeddables (objects stored in DB but without a persistent identity - in other words - without "id"),
- relationships to other Entities,
- any object which is serializable.

Your case seems to be solved using the third or fourth option.

**Storing serializable object**

If you want just to persist the whole object, you should add `implements Serializable` to your `ShoppingCar` and it should be correctly persisted in the database.
However, it will be persisted using Java Serialization (so it'll be a binary representation of the object passed during persistence). That's quite **uncommon** way of achieving your aim.

**Using entity relationships**

Did you consider making `ShoppingCart` an entity? In this way, you can use relationships and persist the whole object when `Reservation` object is saved, i.e.:

```
 @Entity
 public class Reservation implements Serializable {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
      private Long id;

      @OneToOne
      private ShoppingCart cart;
      // ...
    }
```

The example above assumes that exactly one `Reservation` will be connected with exactly one `ShoppingCart`.

Another way of achieving your goal is to extend the `Reservation` entity and add fields for ordered products, i.e.:

```
 @Entity
 public class Reservation implements Serializable {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
      private Long id;

      @ElementCollection
      private Map<DVD, Integer> items;
    }
```

Notice the usage of `Map` as an interface instead of `HashMap` which is always preferred (if not required by the JPA.) Also note that in one structure you can hold both - the item and its quantity bought by the user.

Remember that in this example, the `DVD` should be an Entity (which is quite reasonable, as you probably will store all your items in the database.)

Comment: Your answer is quite clear! Thank you very much!
I prefer the third solution, for the Entity ShoppingCart:
` 
        @Entity 
        public class ShoppingCart implements Serializable { 
            @Id 
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) 
            @ElementCollection //is necessary? 
            private Map<String, ShoppingCartItem> items; 
            private int numberOfItems; 
            … 
        } 
         `
is the ShoppingCart entity right ? 
@ElementCollection is necessary? Should ShoppingCartItem be an Entity ?

Comment: 1. `ShoppingCart` doesn't have to be an entity in the case you'd like to use the latter example. It's because you persist the `DVD` instance and doesn't even use the `ShoppingCart` object. 2. [`@ElementCollection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ElementCollection.html) should be specified if you're persisting a collection/map of basic types or embeddables (in this case the value of the map is a basic type). Sometimes it could be defaulted, but for portability reasons it's good to put it there.

Comment: I am sorry that I didn't specify my question, I mean "Using entity relationships", Entity Reservation refers to an Entity ShoppingCart. Should ShoppingCartItem be an Entity ?

Comment: Yes, relationships (`@OneToOne`, `@OneToMany`, `@ManyToOne` and `@ManyToMany`) are available only for entities.